# Cómo agregar los elementos recorridos en for a un array

Tags: javascript

Así como lo tengo solamente agrega el último elemento al array, qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers > span");

var total = []; // ARRAY
        
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

  total = list[i].innerText;
        
}
```

```html
<div class="numbers">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar:

```
total.push(list[i].innerText)
```